# CSS Overflow with div

Tags: css, overflow, css-float

I want to use overflow on a div to show all div and image, and text to but for this example i used only images.

i need a horizontal scroll, if i only use image its work well with the white-space: nowrap; css but if each images are in a div the sroll disapear and images don't show all.

[Example 3 here](http://www.starsclips.com/testscripts/test-css-overfloat2.html)

the first exemple work if i give a width to a wrapping all div but i can do this methode since all the div are called dynamicaly, it's mean that i can got 1 div to hundred one.

Here the code of the 3rd example

```css
#dmcscroll2 {
  white-space: nowrap; display:
  block; width:660px;
  height:112px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /*overflow :
  -moz-scrollbars-horizontal;*/
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:#000;
}
.div-image{
  float: left;
  width: 125px;
}
```

how can i do for the 3rd technique without knowing the number of div with images a will get from a dynamic javascript call.

You may look at the source code to see more in detail

Comment: You described the problem as if we're a part of your team. I'd say be less descriptive and more clear. ;)

Comment: thank's but it's the best i can do in english he he (i'm french)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `float:left` from `.div-image` CSS and add `display: inline` instead:

```
.div-image{
  display: inline;
  width: 125px;
}
```

That seems to work the way you wanted it to on your example website.

Comment: Hi, i had doubt that something so simple would work but it's working thank's
It's example 3 in the link of the main post